# WSO2 ESB: Using Basic Authentication for a proxy service

Tags: basic-authentication, wso2-esb

I need to expose a proxy service created on WSO2 ESB 4.3.0 using Basic Authentication.

How can that be possible?

Thanks in advance,

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of article written around this chapter refer [1] [2]

[1] http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/11/secure-your-service-with-http-basic.html

[2] http://blog.thilinamb.com/2011/04/how-to-access-web-service-using-http.html

Comment: and also you can find it in wso2 Wiki and library [3] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/HTTP+Basic+Authentication+over+a+Proxy+Server